Calculating Probability of the lim inf of Events
let $(W_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. exponential to the parameter $\lambda=1$ distributed random variables.
Now I would like to calculate
$$\mathbb{P}\bigl(\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\displaystyle W_n}{\displaystyle log(n)}\bigr)= ?$$
How to do this?
I only know how to approach the $\limsup$ by using the Borel-Cantelli-Lemma, but not what to do here.

What you ask is a bit unclear because the argument of your probability is a random variable, not an event. What do you mean by $\mathbb{P}(\liminf_{n\to\infty} W_n/\log(n))$?
Anyway, $\liminf_{n\to\infty} W_n/\log(n)$ is equal to $0$ with probability $1$.
You know that with probability $1$, $W_n\leq 1$ for infinitely many $n$. If you like, you can obtain that from the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma which says that if you have a sequence of independent events whose probabilities sum to infinity, then with probability $1$ infinitely many of them occur.
Thus with probability $1$, we have $W_n/\log(n)\leq 1/\log(n)$ infinitely often, and that implies $\liminf_n W_n/\log(n)=0$. Very similarly one gets that actually $\liminf W_n=0$ with probability $1$. Or even, using the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma more carefully (try it!), that $\liminf_n n W_n=0$ with probability $1$.
